# How can you set a DynamicResource in code-behind if the target is not a FrameworkElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamicresource, freezable

Consider this BindingProxy class which is a subclass of Freezable (so it participates in resource-hierarchy lookups when added to a `FrameworkElement`'s `Resources` collection)...

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable {

    public BindingProxy(){}
    public BindingProxy(object value)
        => Value = value;

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        => new BindingProxy();

    #region Value Property

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Value),
            typeof(object),
            typeof(BindingProxy),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default));

        public object Value {
            get => GetValue(ValueProperty);
            set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }

    #endregion Value Property
}
```

You add it to your XAML like so...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <is:BindingProxy x:Key="TestValueProxy" Value="{DynamicResource TestValue}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

As you can see, `Value` is set to a `DynamicResource` and it will thus automatically track changes to a resource defined by that key, as expected.

Now if you wanted to set up a `DynamicResource` in code-behind instead of XAML, if the target object is a `FrameworkElement`, you would simply call `SetResourceReference` on it, like so...

```
myTextBlock.SetResourceReference(TextBlock.TextProperty, "MyTextResource")
```

However, `SetResourceReference` is only available on `FrameworkElement` objects, not `Freezable`s so you can't use that on `BindingProxy`.

Digging into the source code for `FrameworkElement.SetResourceReference`, you find this...

```
public void SetResourceReference(DependencyProperty dp, object name){
    base.SetValue(dp, new ResourceReferenceExpression(name));
    HasResourceReference = true;
}
```

Unfortunately, `ResourceReferenceExpression`--the 'meat' of how this works--is internal so I can't get to that either.

So in code-behind, how can I set a `DynamicResource` on my `Freezable`-based object to mirror what I can do in XAML?

Comment: Why not to use `DynamicResourceExtension` in code like `proxy.Value = dynamicResourceExtension.ProvideValue(null);` ?

Comment: I had actually tried that, but interestingly, not by passing 'null'.  I was caching the service provider and that was part of the problem.  Lemme see if the 'null' fixes it. (Btw, for completeness, can you make this a code example for others to follow? Just looks better here on SO.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `DynamicResourceExtension` instance in your code:

```
var proxy = new BindingProxy();
var dynamicResourceExtension = new DynamicResourceExtension("TestValue");
proxy.Value = dynamicResourceExtension.ProvideValue(null);
```

If you see the code reference [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/DynamicResourceExtension.cs,19415bc8a1aee0af) you will see that `ProvideValue` returns a `ResourceReferenceExpression` when `serviceProvider` is null. Just almost the same thing that `SetResourceReference` does

Comment: Just giving you a heads-up.  This is what it was used for, and it works flawlessly! Thanks!  Using a Binding with Dynamic Resources: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33816511/168179

Comment: Passing `null` was the missing ingredient. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ResourceReferenceExpression` using reflection:

```
Type type = typeof(System.Windows.Window).Assembly.GetType("System.Windows.ResourceReferenceExpression");
ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructors()[0];
object resourceReferenceExpression = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { "TestValue" });
TestValueProxy.SetValue(BindingProxy.ValueProperty, resourceReferenceExpression);
```

Obviously this code may break if the internal type changes, but there is not much else you can do if you really need to be able to apply a `DynamicResource` to a value of a `Freezable` dynamically.

Comment: Not crazy about having to use Reflection, but considering that's what the Markup Extension already uses, it should be safe.  On a side-note, I'm experimenting with loading a XAML snippet that both creates the instance of, and assigns the DynamicResource, since this *should* still follow the proper rules without relying on reflection.  If that however doesn't work, I'll mark this as the answer and move on.